# How can I detect sequential values in a Numpy array and process it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have a NumPy array that consists of groups of sequential values and I would like to detect the median value(or closest integer) of each group. After that, I should create new arrays by subtracting and adding some values.

Example: data=[100,101,102,103,170,171,172,252,253,254,255,256,333,334,335]

Demand:

the median value of first(closest to median):103,

the median value of second:171,

the median value of third:254,

the median value of forth:334

I want to subtract and add same value of that numbers, let's say 20 than:

final_array =[(83,123), (151,191), (234,274), (314, 354)]

It should not be a median value but it should be a number in a sublist. How can I do it by using python?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi it looks like some homework... what have you tried? what's your code? how would you do the task as a person? then try to traduce this idea to code

Comment: Hi, it is not homework but a part of a project I work on an ECG dataset and I have 1 min ECG record, now I should separate each cycle and don't know how to do.

Comment: I think you might solve your problem by breaking it in parts: 1) find subArrays. 2) calculate median. 3) add and substract. With that in mind. Let me do some questions to you than can clarify every problem (so you can get the solution by yourself).
a- how would look an array with the difference of every value with the previous one? are you familiarized with function `np.diff` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

First lets split the main array to sequential sub-arrays:

```
splitted_data = np.array(np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != 1)[0]+1), dtype=object)
```

essentially we are searching the array [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) the difference between two number is not 1, if the condition is met it [`splits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) it.

The last `1` after the `+` can be changed of course if you are looking for sequences with different difference.

Now since `spillted_data` is an `np.array` with different shaped objects, [`np.median`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) won't work "as-is", so lets [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) that method:

```
vectorized_med = np.vectorize(np.median)
```

Then just extract median with the vectorized function & round it to match closest `int` requirement:

```
medians = np.round(vectorized_med(splitted_data))
```

Now you can construct your final array with a list comprehension:

```
num = 20
final_array = np.array([(i - num, i + num) for i in medians])
```

final output:

```
array([[ 82., 122.],
       [151., 191.],
       [234., 274.],
       [314., 354.]])
```

*Just as a side note, the median of `[100, 101, 102, 103]` is `101.5`.

Comment: I would replace `np.floor` for `np.round` seems more acurate to work with nearest value

Comment: @UlisesBussi sure why not, ill edit it.

Comment: @UlisesBussi I just checked it and it ceils the first value so it depends more on which closest value he is looking for.

Comment: no, that's not right `np.floor(np.median([100,101,102,103]))` returns `101` and `np.round(np.median([100,101,102,103]))` returns 102

Comment: @UlisesBussi Yes, because the median is `101.5` so it ceiled it to `102` *but* still `np.round` is more appropriate here

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution (avoiding `np.vectorize`)

```
import numpy as np

data=np.array([100,101,102,103,170,171,172,252,253,254,255,256,333,334,335])
ddiff = np.diff(data)

#split data
subArrays = np.split(data, np.where(ddiff != 1)[0]+1)

c_val = 20
medians = []
extremes = []
for subArray in subArrays:
    medians.append(np.round(np.median(subArray)).astype(int))
    extremes.append((medians[-1] - c_val, medians[-1] + c_val))

print(extremes)

#outputs
# [(82, 122), (151, 191), (234, 274), (314, 354)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is full numpy approach, avoiding the unequal arrays created by `np.split`. (It only makes a difference if the data is really huge.)

```py
import numpy as np

data = [100, 101, 102, 103, 170, 171, 172, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 333, 334, 335]
data = np.array(data)
# make a list of indices where the step is different from 1
change_pos = np.argwhere(np.diff(data) != 1).squeeze()
# the start of each group is at change_pos+1, and also at position 0
starts = np.append(0, change_pos + 1)
# the end of each group is at change_pos and also at the very end
ends = np.append(change_pos, len(data) - 1)
# the medians are the rounded mean of the start and end values
medians = (data[starts] + data[ends] + 1) // 2
num = 20
# create two columns, subtracting and adding num
final_array = np.c_[medians - num, medians + num]
```